# Как посчитать количество символа в каждой строке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, символы

У меня есть DataFrame в котором в одном из столбов записи разделены символом - ';'

```
data = pd.read_csv(A.csv', sep=',')
А['Name']
```

Вывод:

```
Name:
Ada; BAr
Rab; san; Rap
```

Как мне посчитать количество символов `';'` в каждой строке?

Comment: Ну хоть немного изучите язык. `'Rab; san; Rap'.count(';')`. Даже если не знали, поиск `подсчет вхождений символа в строку` займет меньше времени чем создать вопрос. Цикл по строкам надеюсь не проблема?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [134]: df
Out[134]:
            Name
0       Ada; BAr
1  Rab; san; Rap

In [135]: df['Name'].str.count(';')
Out[135]:
0    1
1    2
Name: Name, dtype: int64
```